# Передача переменных в json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Есть задача вернуть из бд несколько значений по одному ID. Как превратить переменные из БД в JSON формат? или как лучше сделать? Пример кода.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    data: {comand:comand, name:name, email:email, id:id},
   // dataType: 'json',
    url: '/ajaxcontroller.php',

    type: 'POST',

    success: function(data){
       if(comand=2)
       {
           alert(data);
           var data2=$.parseJSON(data);
           alert(data2.name);
       }
    }

});
```

PHP

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($CONNECT,"SELECT *  FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$id'"));

$json = '{"name":2,"login":"Admin","passport":"21242423"}';
echo  $json;
```

При замене на переменные перестает работать.

```
$json = '{"name":$row['name'],"login":$row['email'],"passport":"21242423"}';
```

Comment: json_encode функция выполняющая преобразование структуры данных в строковое представление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$json = '{"name":'.$row['name'].',"login":'.$row['email'].',"passport":"21242423"}';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($CONNECT,"SELECT *  FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$id'"));
$json = json_encode($row);
echo $json;
```